# Gitlab-CI Include and merge mutiple variables section

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I think the problem speak for itselft. I have mutiples included hidden jobs. In my .gitlab-ci.yml and I would like to enjoy the 'variables' section of all of them.

I thought I would have found what I need here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html but:

- Anchors does not allow included files
- !reference cannot be used mutiples times in the 'Variables' section
- extends does not merge the content but take the last one.

If anyone as an idea. Here the behavior I am trying to achieve:
hidden_1.yml

```
.hidden_1:
  variables:
    toto1: toto1
```

hidden_2.yml

```
 .hidden_2
      variables:
        toto2: toto2
```

hidden_3

```
 .hidden_3
      variables:
        toto2: toto3
```

result.yml

```
include: 
  - 'hidden_3'
  - 'hidden_2'
  - 'hidden_1'
Job_test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    toto2: toto3
    toto1: toto1
    toto2: toto3
   script: Echo '$toto1, $toto2, $toto3'
```

Comment: The docs here seem to suggest you can indeed merge variables from multiple extends, If the same variable is defined in each then the clostest scope wins. they give an example of this where you can see the varriables are merged but since both have URL, then the latest value is used https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#merge-details

Comment: Silly me, spent the day the nose in front of the documentation. Apparently I don't know ho to read. Thanks !